# BigQuery API CopyJobConfiguration to add source and desitnation project_id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Team,
Trying to copy a table from one project to another project and using CopyJobConfiguration API call to perform this copy but couldn't add source project_id and destination project_id options to set.

Any Suggestions?

```
    TableId destinationTable = TableId.of(datasetId, destinationTableId);
    TableId sourceTable = TableId.of(datasetId, sourceTableId);

    CopyJobConfiguration configuration = 
        CopyJobConfiguration.newBuilder(destinationTable, sourceTable)
        .build();

    log.info("Configuration: {}",configuration);

    // Instantiate a client.
    BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

    // Create a job ID so that we can safely retry.
    JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    Job copyJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(configuration).setJobId(jobId).build());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TableId.of(project, dataset, table);`. For reference consult this [link](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/TableId.html)